# In Excel, what formula can I use to repeat text in one cell, for a specified amount of times in consecutive rows?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, what formula can I use to repeat text in one cell, for a specified amount of times in consecutive rows?
Example. A2 is the number of times to repeat, B2 is the amount to be repeated and C2, D2, etc is the cells that must receive the repetition?

Comment: what do you have so far? getting any error messages? please post anything you've got. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C2 .... X2 where X is as far as you may want to go in terms of columns

[**updated**:I had transposed A&B]

`=IF(COLUMN()-2<=$A2,$B2,"")` 
and copy right

This works by calculating if the current column position -2 exceeds the value in B2

- So is column C-2 (3-2 =1) greater than the value in B2
- then is column D-2 (4-1 =2) greater than the value in B2 etc

[image]
if you question is more complex than this then you will need to provide further detail

Comment: Ok. Im going to try and explain this.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try and explain this. Column A is the number of repetitions,Column B is the amount that needs to be repeated, and Column C-M receives the repetitions. So lets say for example, 5000 must be repeated 3 times. What formula can you use to get 5000 in 3 columns?

Comment: @Survivor - exactly what I posted.

Comment: Thank you Brettdj, but I don't understand what you are saying? I tried to put in exactly what you said, but it gives me the number of repetitions (3). Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Survivor - sorry, you were right. I had swapped A&B. Now updated

Comment: Sorry it still does not want to work. Can you please specify exactly what you mean by the formula?

Comment: @Survivor see picture, in C2 I put `=IF(COLUMN()-2<=$A2,$B2,"")` and copied to M2

Comment: did you copy that formula in column D and E also? Because it only gives me 5000 in column C?

Comment: @Survivor. yes, copy it through all the way to M2.

Comment: Sorry it does work. Thank you very much. I want to ask another question please. First, column C-M is months, so C is January, but lets say I want to make January column E, Feb=F etc, how do I change the formula to accomadate that the first repetition is in column E etc?

Comment: Sorry, I figured that out. But I have one more question. I have a column named START which contains numbers 1-12 (months) now lets say I want the first repetition to only start in March, which is column (G), how do I do that?